# multiple logins with sql server linked server

Tags: sql-server

I have a database server out there - lets say the url is "the.database".   It has several databases on it - db_a, db_b, db_c - that all require different users and passwords.

I can happily link to one of them like this:

```sql
exec master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server='the.database' @srvproduct='SQL Server'
exec master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtrvname='the.database' @useself='false' 
      @rmtuser='user_a' @rmtpassword='password_a'

select top 10 * from [the.database].db_a.dbo.some_table;
```

And that works great.  For one of them.

However - what I want to do is connect to the server simultaneously with three different logins, and I can't figure out how to do it... in fact - what I'd *really* like is three different linked servers - db_a, db_b, db_c - which all actually point to the.database.... but if you use "sql server" as the product, it seems like the internal server name has to correspond to the url of the actual server?   In the perfect world, I'd love to end up with being able to do:

```sql
select top 10 * from [db_a].some_table
```

where db_a actually means database dba schema dbo on server the.database.

So basically - is there a way to create a linked server with an internal name that doesn't match the external url?   Or is there another way of solving this problem?

Comment: `sp_setnetname` can be used to have the server name resolve to whatever host you like, allowing you to have different names for the same server (I don't know if this will actually work if you try it with different logins, mind you). Synonyms can be used to make remote objects appear local (you cannot synonymize a database, but you can synonymize objects within it). Do note that such setups obscure that you're using linked servers, which is not a good thing, because they make queries considerably less robust, especially if your network isn't 100%.

Comment: thanks - set_netname gave me what I want!  -  I can create a bunch of servers with just arbitrary names, set the netnames all to the real server, and then individually assign permissions to them.   (ty)